# Angular 7+ App fails to show content between <noscript> tags, blank white page

Tags: html, angular, adblock, noscript

My Angular 7 App shows a blank white page with errors shown below.

```
    Refused to load the script '<URL>' because it violates the 
    following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'none'". 
    Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' 
    is used as a fallback.
```

I know that this is because I have the browser extension ScriptSafe installed and that the page loads fine after I allow scripts to be ran on the page.

I have tried adding noscript tags in my index.html to no avail.

```
    <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
      <noscript>Please enable javascript.</noscript>
    </body>
```

I have seen websites that were built with Angular that display at least something before I "allow" them via ScriptSafe and I would like users that are using AdBlockers and Script Blockers etc. to see more then a white page when they first visit.  How do I do this in Angular 7+?

-Thanks

Comment: I just realized that even twitter.com shows a blank white page when scripts are not "allowed" by scriptsafe...also on madewithangular.com half these sites load at least something, the other half...just a white page....is this the state of PWA's today?